# How the probabilities are normalized in one-vs-rest scheme of sklearn Logistic Regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression

In the sklearn LogisticRegression classifer, we can set the `muti_class` option to `ovr` which stands for one-vs-rest, as in the following code snippet:

```
# logistic regression for multi-class classification using built-in one-vs-rest
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
# define dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, n_informative=5, n_redundant=5, n_classes=3, random_state=1)
# define model
model = LogisticRegression(multi_class='ovr')
# fit model
model.fit(X, y)
```

Now, this classifier can assign probabilities to different classes for given instances:

```
# make predictions
yhat = model.predict_proba(X)
```

The probabilities sum to 1 for each instance:

```
array([[0.16973178, 0.46755188, 0.36271634],
       [0.58228627, 0.0928127 , 0.32490103],
       [0.28241256, 0.51175978, 0.20582766],
       ...,
       [0.17922774, 0.71300755, 0.10776471],
       [0.05888508, 0.24924809, 0.69186683],
       [0.25808835, 0.68599321, 0.05591844]])
```

My question: *In the one-vs-rest method, a classifier is trained for each class. Therefore, we expect a probability for each class independent from other classes. How the probabilities are normalized to sum to 1?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py#L432),
multiclass is handled by normalizing the score of each class for the instance x over all classes as follows: the estimated probability that the
instance belongs to class k is given by

[image]

f representing the decision function, K the number of classes.

Answer (score 4):

The probabilities are normalized by dividing by the row sum (i.e. the sum of the class probabilities for each sample), this is the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py#L445):

```py
prob /= prob.sum(axis=1).reshape((prob.shape[0], -1))
```

The code below shows how to use this formula to replicate the model outputs:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# generate some data
X, y = make_classification(n_classes=3, n_features=10, n_informative=5, n_redundant=5, n_samples=1000, random_state=1)

# fit the model
model = LogisticRegression(multi_class='ovr')
model.fit(X, y)

prob_pred = model.predict_proba(X)
print(prob_pred)
# [[0.16973178 0.46755188 0.36271634]
#  [0.58228627 0.0928127  0.32490103]
#  [0.28241256 0.51175978 0.20582766]
#  ...

class_pred = model.predict(X)
print(class_pred)
# [1 0 1 2 0 2 1 2 0 1 1 0 2 1 0 1 2 0 1 0 ...

# replicate the model's outputs
classes = np.unique(y)
n_classes = len(classes)
n_samples = len(y)

prob_pred = np.zeros((n_samples, n_classes))
class_pred = np.zeros(n_samples)

for c in classes:

    y_ = np.where(y == c, 1, 0)

    model = LogisticRegression()
    model.fit(X, y_)

    prob_pred[:, c] = model.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]

prob_pred /= prob_pred.sum(axis=1).reshape((prob_pred.shape[0], -1))
print(prob_pred)
# [[0.16973178 0.46755188 0.36271634]
#  [0.58228627 0.0928127  0.32490103]
#  [0.28241256 0.51175978 0.20582766]
#  ...

class_pred = classes[np.argmax(prob_pred, axis=1)]
print(class_pred)
# [1 0 1 2 0 2 1 2 0 1 1 0 2 1 0 1 2 0 1 0 ...
```